# Where does Quickbooks for Mac store its registration data?

Tags: macos, quickbooks

I'd like to back up the registration of my copy of Quickbooks so in the case of a fresh reinstall I don't have to go through their online registration.

Where is this registration data stored?

Answer (score 0):

Close all active windows.
You do not need to have a company file open, but it will not hurt.
[Press Command-1](https://community.intuit.com/questions/714265-f2-equivalent-on-the-mac) (or F2)
The License Number and Product Code will appear on that screen.
Screen shot that ([typically](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X) Command-Shift-4) and save the screenshot.